# Nginx configuration of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm doing rails deployment with nginx and passenger.
In the nginx configuration file, i want to make nginx run with user "deployer" of usergroup "deployers". So I change the user config to be

```
# /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf                       

user  deployer deployers;
worker_processes  2;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
```

However no matter how many time i restart the service, it still run by user "nobody"

Anyone has experienced this and know how to tell nginx to run with user deployer?
Because the user nginx is run under nobody, it is causing gem errors of no gem detected result in this error page.

```
Error page:
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install
If that didn't work, then maybe the problem is that your gems are installed to //.rvm/gems, while at the same time you set PassengerRuby (Apache) or passenger_ruby (Nginx) to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby. Because of the latter, RVM does not load gems from the home directory.

To make RVM load gems from the home directory, you need to set PassengerRuby/passenger_ruby to an RVM wrapper script inside the home directory:

Login as nobody.
Enable RVM mixed mode by running:
rvm user gemsets
Run this to find out what to set PassengerRuby/passenger_ruby to:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby \
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.44/bin/passenger-config --detect-ruby
If that didn't help either, then maybe your application is being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the nobody user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.
```

Comment: what is the user in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean "nobody"? It came with the default of nginx.conf

Comment: This is the default configuration

    #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  4;

    #error_log  logs/error.log;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  info;

    #pid        logs/nginx.pid;

Answer (score 0):

`nginx.conf` has global parameters that include `user`.  The user and group under which the worker processes run is configured using this parameter.  Change it to the one you want and restart.

Comment: Yes Bala, that what I understood as well which is why I modified it to be 

    user  deployer deployers;